# How to delete the account image in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8

I have edited my profile pic. Now I want to delete it, not simply to change it.

So how to get the default account picture?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find the default account picture under:

```
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Default Account Pictures
```

Note that this is a hidden folder, so you may need to either enable viewing hidden files and folders, or press <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> and paste the path.

[Source](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-desktop/how-to-change-windows-8-profile-picture-back-to/8293b2cd-a83c-4bb2-b918-1aadfc2dd854)

Comment: I can not access this folder from modern UI. [I've posted a new question about it.](http://superuser.com/questions/512796/how-to-show-hidden-folders-in-windows-8-from-the-modern-ui)

Answer (score 7):

The previous answer works, actually. To elaborate: go to C:/users/your user name/AppData/Roaming/Microsoft/Windows/Accountpictures and delete the pictures you want to delete. The AppData folder is hidden, so you'll want to make it visible first (by checking the appropriate box under the Explorer's 'View' tab). Your current picture will be retained, but you can change it in the usual way, and after the change, it will be gone, too.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you change your account picture back to its default:

1. Go to "This PC"
2. Click on "Windows (C:)"
3. Type in "Default Picture" in the search bar.
4. Click on "Default Account Pictures"
5. Click on the "View" tab and then the "Large icons" button
6. Copy the default account image named "user" to desktop.
7. Go to start screen.
8. Right click your profile picture located on top right corner of start screen.
9. Click "Change Account Picture"
10. Open "Browse"
11. Look for the picture you just dragged on to your desktop.
12. Select the picture.
13. Your account picture should be back to the default picture.

See how easy that was. And it only took 13 steps and 45 minutes worth of research.

Answer (score -3):

> C:/users/*your user name*/AppData/Roaming/Microsoft/Windows/Accountpictures

Comment: Umm... that's a path... what I do with it?

Answer (score -4):

try this script to reset the profile picture: [Windows 8.1 User Profile Picture Reset](http://home.arcor.de/levelad/W81UPPR.html)

Kind regards

Pascal

Comment: The script is hosted on external server. It can be changed to malicious code in the future.