# How to show hidden folders in Windows 8 from the modern UI?

Tags: windows-8

I have tried to change my [account image to the default one](https://superuser.com/questions/512582/how-to-delete-the-account-image-in-windows-8/), but the default image is located in the hidden folder

```
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Default Account Pictures
```

I have changed the settings and I can see this folder from Windows Explorer but not in the modern UI. So it was not possible to change the picture to the default.

Comment: Can you see other hidden folders?  If you can see the file through Windows Explorer I don't understand the problem.

Comment: @Ramhound yes, I can see all hidden folders through Windows Explorer, but to change the pic I have to make it through the Modern UI. And then I have to choose the pic. This procedure shows me only visible folders.

Comment: So you no hidden folders while modern ui?  I suggest you copy the file and set it to that.  Otherwise I suppose there are manual ways of setting the file through the registery.  I was able to use the File Explorer to change my account image on my virtual image.

Comment: I would suggest trying to remove the hidden status from the folder (Right-click menu > Properties > Uncheck Hidden option if checked, then tell it to perform this action on all sub-files and folders), add it as your account image, then change the folder back to hidden. Another option is to make a link to the file in a folder that the metro UI can see and navigate to that. Some will work for that.

Answer (score -2):

Copy the user's picture and paste that in My Pictures.

After that, browse from the Modern UI to My Pictures and select User.